# Plot size not getting increased with increasing the figsize values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a subplot using two columns and the plot size is not getting increased with increase in figsize value.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('A Vs B')
ax1.plot(df['X'], df['A'])
ax2.plot(df['X'], df['B'])
```

[FIG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyYt5.png)

Comment: You need to set the figsize inside `plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=....)` because it creates a new figure. The figure created with `plt.figure` will stay empty, so you better remove that call.

Comment: Remove plt.figure and Pass figsize to subplots. You don’t need two of them. The later overrides the former.